# Zend_Navigation overwrite with array?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I currently use zend_navigation via an XML file.

However I need to overwrite the previous breadcrumb to be its dynamic parent, in the controller.

Is this possible? It seems to me that zend_navigation is fairly static and the zend documentation keeps timing out.

Thanks

---

I have put:

```
    public function addAction() {

        $this->view->navigation()->addPage(array(
            'type' => 'uri',
            'label' => 'New page')
        );
```

in my controller but no crumbbar shows up for that page.

Any ideas? $this->navigation() threw a

```
Method "navigation" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
```

Also of note that my crumbBar is in my layout and not individual views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use an array.

What you should do really is create your array and then input it into the factory of the Zend_Navigation to create your pages for you.

Unfortunately my code is too complicated to show an example of how I used it. But I'll provide a simple example...

Once you create your navigation container, you can just add new pages to it.

Like

```
$this->navigation()->addPage(array(
   'type' => 'uri',
   'label' => 'New page'));
```

But you can also use addPages(). This is what I do.

I think you should just wait for the documentation to load back up for you and then look at that. Its really easy in fact.

When you have a more specific question, just ask that and give me a poke. I've had to use Navigation quite a lot so know it quite well.

Additionally, check out #zftalk on freenode. Theres lots of help on there.

Comment: Thank you, is the zend documentation loading for you?

Comment: Yes it is. It loads without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Disable Layout
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();     
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    // Output XML than HTML
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');


    $container = new Zend_Navigation();

    // Replace this section with real dynamic data. 
    $pages = array(
        array(
            'label'  => 'Save',
            'action' => 'save',
        ),
        array(
            'label'  => 'Delete',
            'action' => 'delete',
        ),
    );

    // Add pages
    $container->addPages($pages);
    $this->view->navigation($container);

    // Output the data.
    echo $this->view->navigation()->sitemap();
```

Additionally uses Zend Router for redirecting site.com/sitemap.xml to this controller/function.

Thank you for many developers who help me to reach here.