# Zend_Navigation Sitemap not generating

Tags: php, zend-framework, sitemap, zend-navigation

I'm currently creating a project management system with the Zend Framework 1.12 and I got a problem with the `Zend_Navigation::Sitemap()` method.

I have a controller named `SitemapController` with `indexAction()` inside it who disable the layout. Then, my `/views/scripts/sitemap/index.phtml` script render the sitemap.

Problem, is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"/>
```

It's all I get in the `/sitemap` URI. Even if my `navigation.xml` is filled.

Here's all my code:

**index.phtml**

```
<?php
$this->navigation()->sitemap()->setFormatOutput(true)
                              ->setUseSchemaValidation(false)
                              ->setUseXmlDeclaration(true)
                              ->setUseSitemapValidators(true);
echo $this->navigation()->sitemap()->render($this->navigation);
?>
```

**SitemapController.php**

```
<?php
class SitemapController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
    }
}
```

**Bootstrap.php**

```
/**
* @return Zend_Navigation
*/
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $view = $this->bootstrap('layout')->getResource('layout')->getView();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $view->navigation($navigation);
}
```

**navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
    <nav>
        <home>
            <label>Tableau de Bord</label>
            <controller>index</controller>
            <action>index</action>
        </home>
        <project>
            <label>Projets</label>
            <controller>project</controller>
            <action>index</action>
        </project>
        <tasks>
            <label>Tâches</label>
            <controller>tasks</controller>
            <action>index</action>
        </tasks>
        <messages>
            <label>Messages</label>
            <controller>messages</controller>
            <action>index</action>
        </messages>
    </nav>
</configdata>
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't render the sitemap as it supposed to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any way to change the encoding in Zend_Navigation?

I'd suggest to check encoding while you are constructing the menu tree or from your navigation.xml, perhaps.

### From Zend_Navigation documentation

> Note UTF-8 encoding used by default
>
> By default, Zend Framework uses UTF-8 as its default encoding, and, specific to this case,  Zend\View does as well. Character encoding can be set differently on the view object itself using the setEncoding() method (or the the encoding instantiation parameter). However, since Zend\View\Interface does not define accessors for encoding, it’s possible that if you are using a custom view implementation with the Dojo view helper, you will not have a getEncoding() method, which is what the view helper uses internally for determining the character set in which to encode.
>
> If you do not want to utilize UTF-8 in such a situation, you will need to implement a getEncoding() method in your custom view implementation.

It sometimes happens to me when dealing with ISO-8859-1 and JSON, that it just cuts the output, it occurs to me that might be something with your language.

## UPDATE

This is the code I'm using in my `sitemapAction`:

```
/**
 * Shows the site map.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function sitemapAction()
{
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . DS . 'configs' . DS . 'navigation.xml', 'mainnav');
    $container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $this->view->navigation($container);
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    echo $this->view->navigation()->sitemap();
}
```

Comment: `index.phtml` => UTF-8 ;; `navigation.xml` => UTF-8 ;; `Bootstrap.php` => UTF-8

Comment: Anything? I use Zend_Navigation a lot, and never faced this problem.

Comment: I tried everything I know about Zend_Navigation, but nothing worked.

Comment: How are you trying to display the sitemap? From view? controller? `<?= $this->navigation()->sitemap() ?>`? I'm showing it from the controller, disabling layout and ViewRenderer.

Comment: I tried displaying them from the view and the controller, those are giving the same result.

Comment: I'm running exactly the same code that you provided and I get the expected results :/ http://pastebin.com/RbFYx1dz

Comment: Hmmm, weird. Do you need any other code that can help you finding the problem? I'm not an expert in Zend so I can't find it easely.

Comment: What happens if you comment the `Tâches` node?

Comment: Same result, still nothing. I also tried to replace all spaces in labels by a underscore, but it didn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18160/discussion-between-frederick-marcoux-and-saul-martinez)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Saul Martínez answer, I have written code to generate sitemap. It is not using any XML file but the links can be populated from database. Here is the link:

[Zend_Navigation overwrite with array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320590/zend-navigation-overwrite-with-array/16053480#16053480)